# Content Advisor - Loses Sessions

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

We have a client that wants to lock down thier pc's to only use our web application.

So I've enabled content advisor to only access this site. However it seems to lose the login session and keeps throwing the user back to the login screen. When I disable content advisor the app runs as it should.

Has anybody exprecienced this before, and can anybody help me solve this.

The pcs are Windows XP using ie8

Cheers